# ERROR: function last_insert_id() does not exist

Tags: postgresql

my Query is:

```
-- Table: public.student1

-- DROP TABLE public.student1;

CREATE TABLE public.student1
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('student1_id_seq'::regclass),
    country character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    email character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    section character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    sex character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT student1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.student1
    OWNER to postgres;
```

while running my project the error is:

> ERROR: function last_insert_id() does not exist
>
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: The code you have shown can not generate that error.

Answer (score 1):

`last_insert_id()` is a mysql function, and not available in postgresql.

For postgres use:

1. `INSERT INTO student1() VALUES () RETURNING id` -- no additional query
2. `SELECT LASTVAL()` -- returns latest value obtained with nextval
3. use something specific to your database client library.

Comment: Your project is using a mysql function "last_insert_id()". That part of the project needs to be rewritten to use postgres specific functionality.  And i wouldn't be surprised if you'd find more mysql specific stuff in the project.